# Separating code into DLL's away from exe

Tags: .net, wpf

We update our WPF app multiple times a week, this is a pain point as Customers are repeatedly asked to let the exe through their firewall.

To get around this, I will try taking most of the code (including xaml) out of the exe, so the exe never changes.

The below method seems to work, is there any reason why I should not do it this way? e.g. is it ok to have multiple Application objects?

Project: TestWpfSeperateCodeFromExe

```
namespace TestWpfSeperateCodeFromExe
{
    public class App
    {

        // Entry point method
        [STAThread]
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
                AppView.Main(args);
        }
    }
}
```

Project: View

```
namespace View
{
    public class AppView : Application
    {
        // Entry point method
        [STAThread]
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var app = new AppView();

            app.Run();
        }


        public AppView()
        {
            new MainWindow().Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure DLL's are allowed through the firewall (or whatever control they use)?

Comment: that doesnt make any sense - DLLs arent even recognised by firewalls because their code is executed within the calling process

Comment: ah I see what you mean now - I misunderstood it because the OP says 'let the exe through their firewall' instead of 'let the connections the exe makes through their firewall'.. I thought it was really about passing entire files through

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using another application-object will most likely break many things as you have no direct control over the process - you should avoid that and use simple function/method-calls instead, these work flawlessly and thats what DLLs are for. 
In fact, i actually think this wont be possible in the way you imagined it.

Using DLLs like everbody does has loads of advantages, you can move 99% of your code into the DLL and make the primary entry-point (the EXE-file) absolutely static, theres no need to fiddle around with the application-object.

Comment: thanks for "make the primary entry-point (the EXE-file) absolutely static", this gave me the idea of changing "public class App : Application" to "public class App"

Comment: Making the entry point completely static seems to be the solution. Creating User Control libraries is fine, but they will be referenced by the AppView project, not the entry point (TestWpfSeperateCodeFromExe).

Answer (score 2):

A much better approach would be to move your code (including XAML) to one or several User Control libraries. Then your main EXE would just load these controls.

Comment: can you explain why this is "much better"? I want to keep all code and references in the main exe to a minimum, a User Control Library sounds like it is only useful for storing controls, not applications. Therefore a lot of stuff would still have to reside in the main application project.